# Wrong getBounds() on LineScaleMode.NONE

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have write a simple example that adds a canvas and draw a rectangle with stroke size 20 scale mode none.

The problem is that if I call `getBounds()` first time I will get a correct result but after I call `scale();` the `getBounds()` function will give me a wrong result.

It will take in cosideration the stroke but stroke has scalemode to none and on the screen nothing happens but in the result I will have a x value smaller. Can sombody tell me how can I fix this?

```
   protected var display :Canvas;

    protected function addCanvas():void
    {            
        display = new Canvas();
        display.x = display.y = 50;
        display.width = 100;
        display.height = 100;

        display.graphics.clear();
        display.graphics.lineStyle( 20, 0x000000, 0.5, true, LineScaleMode.NONE );
        display.graphics.beginFill( 0xff0000, 1 );
        display.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        display.graphics.endFill();

        area.addChild( display );
        traceBounce();
    }

    protected function scale():void
    {
        var m :Matrix = display.transform.matrix;
        var apply :Matrix = new Matrix();
        apply.scale( 2, 1 );
        apply.concat( m );

        display.transform.matrix = apply;
        traceBounce();
    }

    protected function traceBounce():void
    {
        trace( display.getBounds( this ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width/height and scaling the same display object can give confusing results. Does your Canvas class do anything unusual (e.g. set the scrollRect or add a mask)?

Also you could try getting bounds of the Canvas' parent instead, or setting cacheAsBitmap on the Canvas and seeing if that helps?

Comment: The example is very simple if you put a canvas for example at 20,20 with a border and start scale the X position of the canvas will not be the same if you trace getBounds but with getRect for example you will see the same result check my sample and add this:

<mx:Button click="addCanvas()" label="add" />
<mx:Button click="scale()" label="scale" />
<mx:Canvas id="area" cacheAsBitmap="true" />